# Change multiple interface IP’s with networkd on coreos

Tags: ip, docker, systemd-networkd

I have a working CoreOS machine where I need to change two virtual network interface IP’s in the /etc/systemd/network file like this:

```
[Match]
Name=interface name

[Network]
Address=ip address.
```

This works great for one interface, but when I add a second interface, which needs a different IP address, like this:

```
[Match]
Name=interface name

[Network]
Address=ip address.
```

[Match]
Name=interface name2

[Network]
Address=ip address2.

This doesn’t work.
I can’t find an example where two interface IP’s are changed anywhere online.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put them in different files, named after their interface. For example, for interfaces named `enp4s0f0`, `enp4s0f1`, `enp4s0f2`, and `enp4s0f3` you would create files for each of them:

```
/etc/systemd/network/enp4s0f0.network
/etc/systemd/network/enp4s0f1.network
/etc/systemd/network/enp4s0f2.network
/etc/systemd/network/enp4s0f3.network
```

Technically the files can be named anything ending with `.network`, but unless you want a configuration that configures multiple interfaces with a `Match` (e.g. to set up DHCP on every interface) then naming the files after their corresponding interfaces eliminates confusion.